# XML - Check for existence of a specific node

Tags: c#, xml

I don't know why I'm having so much trouble with this, but I'm hoping someone can get me pointed in the right direction.

I have these few lines of code :

```
var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(xelementVar.ToString());

if (xDoc.ChildNodes[0].HasChildNodes)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < xDoc.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes.Count; i++)
    {
        var sFormatId = xDoc.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[i].Attributes["formatID"].Value;
        // Do some stuff
    }    
// Do some more stuff
}
```

The problem is that the `xDoc` I'm getting doesn't always have the `formatID` node, so I end up getting a null reference exception, although 99% of the time it works perfectly fine.

**My question :**

How can I check if the `formatID` node exists before I try to read the `Value` out of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if a node does not exist, it returns null.

```
if (xDoc.ChildNodes[0].ChildNode[i].Attributes["formatID"] != null)
    sFormatId = xDoc.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[i].Attributes["formatID"].Value;
```

of you can do it a shortcut way

```
var sFormatId = xDoc.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[i].Attributes["formatID"] != null ? xDoc.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[i].Attributes["formatID"].Value : "formatID not exist";
```

The format is like this.

```
var variable = condition ? A : B;
```

this is basically saying that if the condition is true, then variable = A, otherwise, variable = B.

Comment: You were first to answer, so the credit goes to you - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Could you use [DefaultIfEmpty()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx)?

E.g

```
var sFormatId = xDoc.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[i].Attributes["formatID"]
                                  .Value.DefaultIfEmpty("not found").Single();
```

Or as others have suggested, check that the attribute is not null:

```
if (xDoc.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[i].Attributes["formatID"] != null)
```

Comment: +1 for the `DefaultIfEmpty` suggestion, I had totally forgot about that. I ended up using the `null` check before trying to read the value.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
            if (xDoc.ChildNodes[0].HasChildNodes)
            {   
                foreach (XmlNode item in xDoc.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes)
                {
                    string sFormatId;
                    if(item.Attributes["formatID"] != null)
                       sFormatId = item.Attributes["formatID"].Value;

                    // Do some stuff
                }     
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for the re-factoring suggestion, I've switched it over to using a `foreach` instead of a `for`.

Answer (score 1):

you can check that like this

```
 if(null != xDoc.ChildNodes[0].ChildNode[i].Attributes["formatID"])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a cleaner way to do this would be:

```
var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(xelementVar.ToString());

foreach(XmlNode formatId in xDoc.SelectNodes("/*/*/@formatID"))
{
    string formatIdVal = formatId.Value; // guaranteed to be non-null
    // do stuff with formatIdVal
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In most case we face issues because an XPath does not exists, It returns null and our code breaks because of the InnerText.

You can only check XPath exists or not and it returns null when does not exist.

```
if(XMLDoc.SelectSingleNode("XPath") <> null)
  ErrorCode = XMLDoc.SelectSingleNode("XPath").InnerText
```